# How do I find the Album ID?

Tags: json, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to figure out what the id of this url is? https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151316456544622.551539.197509829621&type=3

I don't need to do it with code, I just need the number to plug into a JSON script I already have working.

I can't seem to extract the correct number from this page, other page aren't giving me an issue though..

Answer (score 1):

If you have album `URI` like you have mentioned in your question, Album ID is the string between `a.` and first `.` in the `set` parameter of album url.

For example, in the url

> https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151316456544622.551539.197509829621&type=3

Album ID should be `10151316456544622`

Comment: That's what I've been using but nothing is returned when visiting: https://graph.facebook.com/10151316456544622/photos?fields=picture,name,source&limit=10

Comment: Are they private photos or something?

Comment: User may have permission settings for not sharing data with apps...BTW I am assuming you have user's Valid `Access Token` with `user_photos` permission and you are passing access token as well with parameters, then only you can query the graph api for the photos in album otherwise you will get empty response.

Comment: I'm not using access tokens or permissions, they're not needed with my script. Neither is a FB App, I'm just pulling the JSON from the Open Graph.